# UITableViewCell UIView Alignment issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, swift3

I design custom table view cell. When I scroll TableView then Cell View move x position of the first and last cell. Any idea why this problem has occurred.?

I put some code and image for your understanding the problems.

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CreateQuestionViewCell
        //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CreateQuestionViewCell

        //let subview = cell.viewWithTag(1)!

        //let textDetail = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
        cell.quesLbl.text = ((arrTableData[indexPath.row] as! Question).que).convertHTMLtoSymbols()

        //let edit = cell.viewWithTag(3) as? UIButton
        cell.editBtn.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.editBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(EditButActions(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        //let deleteBut = cell.viewWithTag(4) as? UIButton
        cell.deleteBtn.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.deleteBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteButActions(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        if NotEditable {
            cell.editBtn.isHidden = true
            cell.deleteBtn.isHidden = true
        } else {
            cell.editBtn.isHidden = false
            cell.deleteBtn.isHidden = false
        }
        cell.quesLbl.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 14)!
        let desiredWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 60
        let size: CGSize = cell.quesLbl.sizeThatFits(CGSize.init(width: desiredWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        cell.quesLbl.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.quesLbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        if NotEditable {
            cell.subview.frame = CGRect.init(x: 10, y: 10, width: Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40), height: Int(20 + size.height))
        } else {
            cell.subview.frame = CGRect.init(x: 10, y: 10, width: Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40), height: Int(50 + size.height))
        }
        cell.subview.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
        cell.subview.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        cell.subview.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        // SubView.layer.masksToBounds = true;

        cell.subview.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.init(red: 200 / 255, green: 200 / 255, blue: 200 / 255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        cell.subview.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.init(width: 0.5, height: 0.5)
        cell.subview.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
        cell.subview.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        cell.subview.layer.masksToBounds = false
        //cell.subview.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.subview.bounds, cornerRadius: cell.subview.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        return cell
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Where are you reloading your tableView from? Are you doing that from the Main thread?

Comment: @BadhanGanesh Thanks for the reply. Yes, I reload in the main thread but when I scroll constantly up and down than the top view little move x position in Cell. Look into the image. :)

Answer (score 0):

So, remember that the cells are reused, and anytime you add anything to a cell in `cellForRowAt:`, you are adding it to every subsequent cell that is displayed by the table.

Set up everything you can in the storyboard cell prototype. Add the buttons and subviews, set the targets, and add any constraints using the storyboard interface builder.

Then in `cellForRowAt:`, you'll just need to set anything that changes from cell to cell, text strings in labels or images in image views... If you use buttons in the cell, continue to set the button tag like `cell.editBtn.tag = indexPath.row`, so as to identify the cell in the buttons target function. However, avoid changing the cell directly in the target function, rather get the data from the data source based on the tag, and use `reloadData` to redraw the table.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank for your reply. I set all the view in cell and access form tag but my question is when I  scroll table view then top most cell views move little x position like in the image. What is the reason and how can I resolve it. Thanks

Comment: The reason is because you are manipulating cell.subview and interfering with the layout of the table. Take out all the cell.subview calls (especially frame changes) and 'cell.layoutIfNeeded()', and you should be fine. UITableView takes good care of laying out the cells.